# How to make Xamarin.Mac Scriptable(AppleScript)?

Tags: c#, applescript, xamarin.mac

I am working on Visual Studio for mac (Cocoa with C#) for a while. All I wanted to do is to make my app scriptable i.e., it could be able to accept commands from script editor. 
Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve it?

Comment: Is your Model (data) layer is built out of Cocoa classes? If so, you should be able to implement Apple event support using macOS’s high-level CocoaScripting framework. But I’m guessing it’s not, in which case while it is possible to install low-level Apple event handlers directly via `NSAppleEventManager` and create your own Controller layer on top of those, it requires a lot of old-school technical knowledge and serious hard work. With the future of Apple event-based automation looking increasingly shady, you’d be better throwing a JavaScript interpreter in an XPC Service and call it done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know about the model layer you're talking about. I am using visual studio for mac and I am currently working only with window controllers and windows.

Comment: See [Apple’s definition](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) of Model-View-Controller app architecture. The Model layer manages all your business data, a View-Controller layer provides user input and output. A “scriptable app” has a single Model layer and two independent VCs—one for GUI access, the other for scripting access. If you don’t already have [clean separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) between Model and GUI code, you are in a bad place to start adding scripting support.